# Scope of a callback function

Tags: javascript, scope, xmlhttprequest

I want to implement a function which performs ajax requests (response is json) until there will be no "next" property in response. After that i need to perform some callback function. What is the best way for this? My code below doesn't work because of the wrong callback's scope, and i cannot imagine how to pass it correctly.

```
_requestPhotos = function(url, callback) {
  getYFContent(url, function(data) {
    // some actions

    if (!!data.next) {
      _requestPhotos(data.next, callback);
    } else {
      callback(smth);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no obvious errors from the script you've posted. For example, an equivalent test could look like this:

```
alertResult = function(text) {
   console.log("Result is: " + text);
}

doRecursive = function(data, callback) {
   if(!!data.next) {
      doRecursive(data.next, callback);
   } else {
      callback(data.value);
   }
}

var d = { value: 1, next: { value: 2, next: { value: 3 }}};

doRecursive(d, alertResult);
```

The log result is `"Result is: 3"`, which is what you'd expect.

The error is elsewhere. How are you calling this the first time, what is the callback you're passing to it (and how is it defined) and what exactly does getYFContent do?

Comment: This is not just a recursive function. The problem is that "getYFContent" is ajax request function and all the actions are described in its second argument which is a callback function (like in $.get).

Comment: (cont) ...I want to fill "photos" array with proper values. To get them i should make requests consistently one after another. And this is the problem - getYFContent() calls recursively and callback (function which must perform after all requests are sent and we've got all the photoes) fn's scope is only first iteration.

Comment: Ah right - well can you add another argument to `getYFContent`? that way you can keep passing the callback around.